# Page re-inits on navigating back to a page

Tags: nativescript

I've got a page of RadListView - I scroll down, interact etc - when I navigate to another page and then do topframe.back() - the original page's ListView loses it's last state - the entire page is rebuilt.

Anyway for it to not to re-init the page...I know in native Android the default behavior is to have a nested pages of Activities - so can always go back to the last state.

Comment: Hi dashman, This issue has been reported in this issue in GitHub https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2852 . The fix will be available in the upcoming NativeScript release.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the RadListView does not remember its state out-of-the-box at this very moment. What I have done to resolve this issue is to "cache" the scrollIndex and pass it on the **loaded** event for my RadListView.

e.g.

list-page.xml

```
 <lv:RadListView id="rad-list" items="{{ dataItems }}" 
                 loaded="onListLoaded" itemTap="onItemTap">
```

list-page.ts

```
export function onListLoaded(args: RadListwModule.ListViewEventData) {
    list = <RadListwModule.RadListView>args.object;

    if (list.items) {
        list.scrollToIndex(roversViewModel.get("cachedIndex"));
    }
}

// onItemTap is the event where I update the cached index
export function onItemTap(args:RadListwModule.ListViewEventData) {
    var tappedItemIndex = args.itemIndex;
    roversViewModel.set("cachedIndex", tappedItemIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but last time I used scrollToIndex() all it does is make sure the item is visible - could be at the top, middle or bottom. So if you left the page with the item in a gray area - the position would not be restored exactly right? I'm wondering if know the scroll index and the item height - you have the y offset, whether you can call the parent scrollview and scroll to that exact y position.

Comment: In my case the when using scrollToIndex(0 the item is rendered at the top of the page with perfect alignment (using staggered layout for the RadListView and grid with image and labels for the item-template)